How to copy and insert cells into a google sheet
I have data like this:
  A    B     C       D       E       F       G       H
1 Name Phone Item(1) Cost(1) Item(2) Cost(2) Item(3) Cost(3) ...could go up to 30
2 John 55555 Hat     5       Shoes   10      Tie     25
3 Sue  88888 Dress   50
4 Joe  99999 Tie     25      Hat     5

But I need to move all the data into the first column to sort and add up like this:
  A    B     C       D       E       F       G       H
1 Name Phone Item(1) Cost(1) Item(2) Cost(2) Item(3) Cost(3) ...could go up to 30
2 John 55555 Hat     5
3            Shoes   10      
4            Tie     25
5 Sue  88888 Dress   50
6 Joe  99999 Tie     25      
7            Hat     5

I think my steps are:

find "Item" then scan the row where Item was found
If the cell is not blank,
Copy the data of the non blank cell AND the cell next to it
Insert a new row AFTER the cell where the data was found
Paste the Copied cells into the new row under the first "Item(1) Cost(1)"

Heres Where I am:
    // Find the word "Item"
    let ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive() 
       .createTextFinder("Item")
       .matchEntireCell(false)
       .matchCase(false)
       .matchFormulaText(false)
       .ignoreDiacritics(true)
       .findAll(); 
 
    ranges.forEach(
      function (range) {
        {Scan all the cells in the column and do this <== this is where I need help!}
             ranges.getRange('J5').activate();
             ranges.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(ranges.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
             ranges.getActiveRange()
                 .offset(0, 0, 1, ranges.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()) 
                 .activate();
             ranges.getRange('G5:H5').activate();
             ranges.getRange('J6:K6')
                 .copyTo(ranges.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);

Can I get an assist?
see above sorry I put it all there

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your situation, the format of your showing table is always the same. Is my understanding correct? If it's no, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide more sample input including your expected various situations and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

This is [basically] the data I have been given
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qddeS4j9HSe_uR4m0wPl4Z5kiSJqAClp3cr9B5qrPjM/edit?usp=sharing

If the format of your showing table is always the same, how about the following sample script?
Sample script:
Please set the source and destination sheet names.
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "Sheet1";
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet2";

  // ref: https://github.com/tanaikech/UtlApp?tab=readme-ov-file#splitarray
  function splitArray(array, size) {
    if (!array || !size || !Array.isArray(array)) {
      throw new Error("Please give an array and split size.");
    }
    return [...Array(Math.ceil(array.length / size))].map((_) =>
      array.splice(0, size)
    );
  }

  // Retrieve source and destination sheet objects.
  const delimiter = "@@@";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [srcSheet, dstSheet] = [srcSheetName, dstSheetName].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));

  // Retrieve values from the source sheet.
  const [, ...srcValues] = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Create an array.
  const obj = srcValues.reduce((m, [a, b, ...c]) => {
    const k = `${a}${delimiter}${b}`;
    const s = splitArray(c, 2).filter(e => e.some(f => f.toString())).map((e, i) => [...(i == 0 ? [a, b] : [null, null]), ...e]);
    return m.set(k, m.has(k) ? [...m.get(k), ...s] : s);
  }, new Map());
  const ar = [...obj.values()].flatMap(e => e);

  // Put array to destination sheet.
  dstSheet.getRange(2, 1, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);
}

Testing:
When this script is run, the following result is obtained. Here, your showing table was used. It seems that the situation of "To" is the same with your expected result.
From:

To:

References:

reduce()
map()
Map


that worked great!   Thanks for the help.
I don't quite understand the code enough to tell how you are NOT adding the first 2 columns to the array?  If I understood it a lil more then I could increase or decrease the number of "frozen columns"
As stated above, here is a link to the data I am working with:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qddeS4j9HSe_uR4m0wPl4Z5kiSJqAClp3cr9B5qrPjM/edit?usp=sharing

@user3018153 Thank you for replying. About that worked great! Thanks for the help., I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. But, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?
